What is wrong with this `.spec` file to generate a bundle for macOS?
I'm trying to generate a bundle for macOS for this project. The .spec file from the repository works fine on Windows, but when I try to use it for macOS, it fails.
I've tried to fix it for MacOS by modifying it, resulting in the following:
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
import os.path
from pathlib import Path
from PyInstaller.compat import is_darwin, is_win
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import copy_metadata, collect_data_files, collect_all


datas = []

datas += collect_data_files("transformers", include_py_files=True)
datas += collect_data_files("lightning")
datas += collect_data_files("lightning_fabric")
datas += collect_data_files("speechbrain")
datas += collect_data_files("pyannote")
datas += collect_data_files("asteroid_filterbanks")
datas += collect_data_files("whisperx")
datas += collect_data_files("librosa")

datas += copy_metadata("tqdm")
datas += copy_metadata("regex")
datas += copy_metadata("requests")
datas += copy_metadata("packaging")
datas += copy_metadata("filelock")
datas += copy_metadata("numpy")
datas += copy_metadata("tokenizers")
datas += copy_metadata("pillow")
datas += copy_metadata("huggingface_hub")
datas += copy_metadata("safetensors")
datas += copy_metadata("pyyaml")

datas += [("res", "res")]
datas += [("config.ini", ".")]
datas += [(".env", ".")]
datas += [("venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/customtkinter", "customtkinter")]
datas += [("venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch", "torch")]
datas += [("venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchgen", "torchgen")]
datas += [("venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/speech_recognition", "speech_recognition")]
datas += [("venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/moviepy", "moviepy")]
datas += [("venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dotenv", "dotenv")]
datas += [("venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai", "openai")]

hiddenimports = [
    "huggingface_hub.repository",
    "pytorch",
    "sklearn.utils._cython_blas",
    "sklearn.neighbors.typedefs",
    "sklearn.neighbors.quad_tree",
    "sklearn.tree",
    "sklearn.tree._utils",
    "darkdetect",
    "tkinter.font",
    "tkinter.ttk",
    "cmath",
    "pickletools",
    "unittest.mock",
    "aifc",
    "proglog",
    "imageio",
    "decorator",
]

block_cipher = None

debug = True
if debug:
    options = [("v", None, "OPTION")]
else:
    options = []

a = Analysis(
    ["src/app.py"],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=datas,
    hiddenimports=hiddenimports,
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

macos_icon = "res/macos/icon.icns"
windows_icon = "res/windows/icon.ico"

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    options,
    exclude_binaries=True, #NEW
    name="Audiotext",
    debug=debug,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=debug,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file="res/macos/entitlements.plist" if is_darwin else None,
    icon=windows_icon if is_win else macos_icon,
)

coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name="Audiotext",
)

app = BUNDLE(
    coll,
    name="Audiotext.app",
    icon=macos_icon,
    bundle_identifier="com.henestrosadev.audiotext",
    version="2.3.0",
    info_plist={
        "NSPrincipalClass": "NSApplication",
        "NSAppleScriptEnabed": False,
        "NSHighResolutionCapable": True,
        "NSMicrophoneUsageDescription": "Allow Audiotext to record audio from your microphone to generate transcriptions.",
    }
)

Now, it generates the bundle, but when I open the generated file, I always get a ModuleNotFoundError. For example, the error I have now is ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openai'. I've fixed it by adding this line, as I've done with te rest of the previous missing modules:
datas += [("venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai", "openai")]

Now, the error I get is ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydantic'. Something is wrong, because it doesn't make sense to manually add all of the program's packages.

The problem was related to the pathex, because for some reason PyInstaller only took the src directory of the project. I added the site-packages directory from the venv directory to the pathex.
The file is now as follows:
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
import os.path
from pathlib import Path
from PyInstaller.compat import is_darwin, is_win

import sys ; sys.setrecursionlimit(sys.getrecursionlimit() * 5)

relative_site_packages_path = "venv/Lib/site-packages" if is_win else "venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages"

datas = [
    (f"{relative_site_packages_path}/customtkinter", "customtkinter"),
    (f"{relative_site_packages_path}/transformers", "transformers"),
    (f"{relative_site_packages_path}/lightning", "lightning"),
    (f"{relative_site_packages_path}/lightning_fabric", "lightning_fabric"),
    (f"{relative_site_packages_path}/speechbrain", "speechbrain"),
    (f"{relative_site_packages_path}/pyannote", "pyannote"),
    (f"{relative_site_packages_path}/asteroid_filterbanks", "asteroid_filterbanks"),
    (f"{relative_site_packages_path}/whisperx", "whisperx"),
    (f"{relative_site_packages_path}/librosa", "librosa"),
    ("res", "res"),
    ("config.ini", "."),
    (".env", "."),
]

hiddenimports = [
    "huggingface_hub.repository",
    "sklearn.utils._cython_blas",
    "sklearn.neighbors.quad_tree",
    "sklearn.tree",
    "sklearn.tree._utils",
]

block_cipher = None

debug = False
if debug:
    options = [("v", None, "OPTION")]
else:
    options = []

a = Analysis(
    ["src/app.py"],
    pathex=[relative_site_packages_path],
    binaries=[],
    datas=datas,
    hiddenimports=hiddenimports,
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

macos_icon = "res/macos/icon.icns"
windows_icon = "res/windows/icon.ico"

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    options,
    exclude_binaries=True, #NEW
    name="Audiotext",
    debug=debug,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=debug,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file="res/macos/entitlements.plist" if is_darwin else None,
    icon=windows_icon if is_win else macos_icon,
)

coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name="Audiotext",
)

app = BUNDLE(
    coll,
    name="Audiotext.app",
    icon=macos_icon,
    bundle_identifier="com.henestrosadev.audiotext",
    version="2.3.0",
    info_plist={
        "NSPrincipalClass": "NSApplication",
        "NSAppleScriptEnabed": False,
        "NSHighResolutionCapable": True,
        "NSMicrophoneUsageDescription": "Allow Audiotext to record audio from your microphone to generate transcriptions.",
    }
)

This solves the issue. However, I have another problem now because the Audiotext.app file won't open, while the Audiotext executable from the dist/Audiotext directory does. But it is not related to this topic, so I'll mark this as the answer.
